# Cloud Watch Metric + AWS Lambda + Python

Tags: python, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using AWS API Gateway + AWS Lambda to build a REST API. I am using pytjon and logging as my log library. The Cloud Watch monitor some metric automatically, e.g, invocation times, error count, ...

So imagine that I have a error inside my lambda function. The Cloud Watch metrics show me with erro count. 
Is it possible to find the log of the exactly the request (the AWS Lambda log) that generated the error?

Does anyone has some tips ho to monitor and debug in this situation?

Comment: Your question is confusing as written. I think it can be distilled down to "How do I find the log message in CloudWatch Logs that generated a CloudWatch alert?". The part about Python and Lambda don't appear to be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, today there are some 3rd party tools that give you this perspective: filter the list of invocations by the failing ones, and drill down to a specific one.
In particular, it can direct you specifically to the log group, and the logs that have been written during this invocation.

In addition, if you know approximately how the failing logs look like, then you can try and search them with cloudwatch-insights (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AnalyzingLogData.html), which is another great tool to filter logs of a specific lambda with advanced queries.

Disclosure: I work for Lumigo, a company that helps you do exactly that.

Answer (score -1):

There is no direct way of linking the automatic metrics(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-metrics.html) to logs on cloudwatch.

The error, exceptions and timeout errors do get logged but can't be traced from the metric.

Comment: The question is specifically about how to find the log message that generated a CloudWatch Logs Alert.

Comment: Hmm interesting .. May be the answer is not appropriate then..backtracking metrics to application logs? Not sure there is a way..will look out for the correct answer..and remove this one

Comment: CloudWatch Logs is pretty terrible at alerts and doesn't really provide useful search capabilities. The issue raised in the question is a major pain point with CloudWatch Logs and I'm not aware of any solution other than pushing the log data to another service that provides better capabilities.

Comment: Yes i am aware.. We ended up choosing aws elastisearch which is managed elk.

Comment: But even then, backtracking metrics to errors is not possible unless the metric is logged programmatically by the app.

Comment: The question is specifically about alerts coming from CloudWatch Logs. Like you can configure it to generate a CloudWatch alert when the text "Exception" appears in a log message. But like you said there is no way to back-track that to the actual error message. Other logging services like Loggly and LogEntries provide that capability, and can even include the entire log message in the alert email.

Comment: When I used lambda, I did not see the automatic metrics go to cloudwatch logs. Cloudwatch logs only had logs related to lambda function io and error streams.. I don't think it's a search flexibility issue with cloudwatch which it lacks.. It may not be possible overall.. But I would wait for 2nd opinion from someone who has used lambda very recently.

Comment: Lambda provides the functionality of sending all your function's log messages to CloudWatch Logs. If you didn't see all your function's logs in CloudWatch Logs then you weren't using the built-in logging function provided by Lambda.

Comment: It did send all my function logs.. I meant automatic metrics logged by lambda service such as invocation count..neways I will try and check.

Comment: Like I said, the metrics for log errors don't show up automatically, it's an extra configuration step you have to take in CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: Just for clarity I meant automatic metrics mentioned on this page. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-metrics.html

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong and that's what the question is regarding. Those would be even more difficult to tie back to logs than the alerts I was talking about.

Comment: Yes.. That's what the question is about. Tracking the to request is not possible. But May be  some sense can made out by tallying the timestamp. I think this is not possible as these metric instrumentations  will never make it to cloudwatch logs . But somehow from ur comments, I thought you meant these logs make it cloudwatch but you cannot configure alerts using cloudwatch search features..

Comment: All those items included in the Errors metric do show up in the Lambda CloudWatch Logs also.

Comment: Yes I have seen exception, errors and timeouts in the cloudwatch logs.